# use grep to output characters not in pattern

Tags: regex, grep

I want to grep a file for a pattern but display another part of the line that is not in the pattern.

Here is my file:

```
Function Process1 took [66] ms
Function Process2 took [1381] ms
Function Process1 took [1501] ms
Function Process2 took [41] ms
```

I want to find the rows that match "Process2" but only output the timing in the square brackets.

So the output I want is:

```
1381
41
```

Answer (score 1):

These commands both work...

```
grep Process2 file.txt | awk '{print $4}' | egrep -o '[^][]+'
grep Process2 file.txt | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/[][]//g'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -oP 'Process2.*\[\K[0-9]+'
```

`-o` outputs only the matched text rather than the whole line.
`\K` dumps the character that were matched up to it, when using `-P`erl mode.

> ```
> $ echo """Function Process1 took [66] ms
> Function Process2 took [1381] ms
> Function Process1 took [1501] ms
> Function Process2 took [41] ms""" | grep -oP 'Process2.*\[\K[0-9]*'
> 1381
> 41
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to tell you not one but 2 solutions (with slight nuances):

**Option 1: Recognize the `[` and `]`**

If your key to find your field is the `[` and `]` you may use this:

```bash
grep Process2 infile | sed "s/.*\[//" | sed "s/].*//"
```

In this example you...

1. First grep the lines
2. Then you search (first `sed` with the `s` command) "any character string ending in `[`" ( identified by `/.*[/` ) and substitute it by "nothing" ( identified by `//` ).
3. You search (second `sed`) "the string `]` followed by any sequence of characters" and change it by "nothing".

**Option 2: Extract the 4th field**

If your key to find your field is to know that it is in the 4th position, you may extract it and later clean it from the brackets with this:

```bash
grep Process2 infile | cut --fields=4 --delimiter=" " | sed "s/\[//" | sed "s/\]//"
```

In this case:

1. You grep your interesting lines.
2. You extract the fourth field, which results in the string with the brackets, like for example `[41]`
3. You change with the `sed`s the `[` for nothing and the `]` for nothing too.

**Tested session**

This is a tested session:

```bash
xavi@guarra:~/tmp$ cat infile
Function Process1 took [66] ms
Function Process2 took [1381] ms
Function Process1 took [1501] ms
Function Process2 took [41] ms
xavi@guarra:~/tmp$ grep Process2 infile
Function Process2 took [1381] ms
Function Process2 took [41] ms
xavi@guarra:~/tmp$ grep Process2 infile | sed "s/.*\[//" | sed "s/].*//"
1381
41
xavi@guarra:~/tmp$ grep Process2 infile | cut --fields=4 --delimiter=" " | sed "s/\[//" | sed "s/\]//"
1381
41
xavi@guarra:~/tmp$
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use grep + sed:

```
grep Process2 myfile.txt | sed 's/.*[\([0-9]+\).*/\1/'
```